# Dropdown menu button not reacting

Tags: javascript, button, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I've created a code for a dropdown menu. When I press on the "Account" button it should roll out settings.  Rather than classes I'm using data-attributes to target the elements better.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/signin" class="udlite-btn udlite-btn-medium udlite-btn-primary udlite-heading-sm"><span>Sign in</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/signup" class="udlite-btn udlite-btn-medium udlite-btn-primary udlite-heading-sm"><span>Sign up</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Dropdown structure -->
        <div class="dropdown"data-dropdown>
        <button class="link" data-dropdown-button>Account</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span>Settings</span>
            <a href="/settings/profile">Profile Settings</a>
            <a href="/settings/security">Security Settings</a>
            <!-- Additional Dropdown Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #c6b497;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.link:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* .dropdown.active > .link, */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown.active > .link + .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

JS

In my JS code, I'm using data-attributes rather than classes. It allows us to target the element based on the value of the data attribute.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const dropdownButton = event.target.closest("[data-dropdown-button]");
    const dropdownMenu = event.target.closest("[data-dropdown]").querySelector(".dropdown-menu");

    if (dropdownButton) {
      dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll("[data-dropdown] .dropdown-menu").forEach(menu => {
        if (menu !== dropdownMenu) {
          menu.classList.remove("active");
        }
      });
    }
  });
  console.log('Clicked element:', event.target);

});
```

Also there's no error sited on the web browser console.